# bxSlider jquery showing random slides?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, slider, bxslider

Hi guys I am using the jquery bxslider plugin, and for some reason it shows random slides, it doesn't start at one, and sometimes it will show the first slide multiple times, and some slides never?

I am using very simple code, I have not edited the .js files you can see it in working (..working but random slides) on viifit.com

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#slider1').bxSlider();
 });

 $(function(){
 var slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider({
  controls: false
 });

 $('#go-prev').click(function(){
 slider.goToPreviousSlide();
 return false;
 });

 $('#go-next').click(function(){
 slider.goToNextSlide();
return false;
 });
});

$(function(){
$('#slider1').bxSlider({
auto: true,
autoControls: false
});
}); 
</script>

<div id="slider1">
<div><img src="slide1.png"></div>
<div><img src="slide2.png"></div>
<div><img src="slide3.png"></div>
<div><img src="slide4.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, this slider is a total JS mess. The author should have mentioned that is actually a : "*Infinite but jumpy laggy slider.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your script, it's crazy.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        controls: false,
        auto:true,
        autoControls: false
    });

    $('#go-prev').click(function(){
        slider.goToPreviousSlide();
        return false;
    });

    $('#go-next').click(function(){
        slider.goToNextSlide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can't test this locally right now, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I was using the script that said how to use it on the actual slider website, I thought it was a widely used slider but I guess nova next time? thanks again though works perfect!

Comment: No. bxlsider is a wonderful plugin. I've used it in a lot of projects. It was a lack of understanding jQuery on your part that caused the problem. There were a lot of errors (including syntax error) on your original code.